# How do I replace the values of a pandas column without knowing the existing value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which has randomly generated numbers below. Is there a way of changing the values to 0 of columns  'account', 'number', 'type', 'sun'?

| Name | account | number | type | sun |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | 558 | 787 | 878 | 454 |

I would like to replace these digits with 0.

I tried `df['account'] = 0` and `df['account'].replace(0)`, but I think the str.replace method assumes you knowing what you want to replace.

I want to make it so it is a blanket, replacing any value that may be populated there, and it is not relying on knowing what is already present.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a value to multiple columns at once, like this:

```
df[['account', 'number', 'type', 'sun']] = 0
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Name  account  number  type  sun
0  Tom        0       0     0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "it is not relying on knowing what is already present" means you don't know column names, but only want to replace numbers, this method would work:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: 0 if str(x).isnumeric() else x)
```

Output:

```
  Name  account  number  type  sun
0  Tom        0       0     0    0
```